# Command line software to batch convert TIFF to indexable PDF

Tags: pdf, indexing, ocr, tiff, document-conversion

I need a utility to batch convert TIFF files to indexable PDF's. The software needs to run on linux and must work from the command line. The software does not need to be open source. I've tried the conversion using tesseract and hocr2pdf however they produce PDF's with garbled text (Note: the text is only garbled if you "select all" text in the PDF). I've found other utilities but they only run under Windows or don't work from the command line. Thanks in advance.

Comment: perhaps [this](http://www.moreno.marzolla.name/software/scan_to_pdf/) can help

Comment: As I noted in my question, I already wrote a program to do the conversion using tesseract and hocr2pdf. To my knowledge, hocr2pdf is the the only open source tool capable of making an indexable PDF document. Your link doesn't outline anything I didn't already know, sorry.

Comment: There's two problems here - getting the OCR done, then converting to PDF. I wonder if the problem would be easier to search for if you look to OCR your TIFF into plain text first, and then you can use something like `wkhtmltopdf` to convert it to a PDF afterwards?

Comment: Also a good suggestion, however, wkhtmltopdf doesn't maintain the integrity of the original document. It only creates a new PDF using only the text from the original TIFF file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several tools (including Abbyy) I decided on: [Vividata](http://www.vividata.com/index.html). They have decent pricing, run under Linux, and don't have a page per year limit.

Answer (score 1):

Mogrify should be able to help you:

http://linux.die.net/man/1/mogrify

Comment: I don't see an option to make the converted image indexable. Can you provide a sample usage?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactlyu what you are looking for:

http://ocr4linux.com/en:start

Command line OCR tool for Linux based on best on the market OCR from ABBYY. (Disclaimer: I work for ABBYY)

Comment: Thanks but I tried purchasing this software and my experience was awful. It took several days for a salesperson to even respond and I was quoted twice what was listed on the website. Apparently they have different pricing for people in Europe and the United States.

Comment: Why did not you just purchase online? Sales do not deal with this product very often, somethimes there can be a confusion

Answer (score 0):

This answer is oblique and only partial.  Disregard if it does not apply to you.

There may exist such software, but I am not familiar with it.  If your need is strong enough that you will write 2000 lines of code or so to meet it, then there is the Linux-oriented [Libpoppler,](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/libpoppler-dev) which gives you the interface to write a program to make its own, custom PDF, exactly the way you want it.  Unfortunately, Libpoppler though valuable is not particularly pleasant to code to; and, unfortunately, if you do code to it, then you will probably find yourself reading long tracts of [the PDF standard.](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html)

If you do write such software, you might consider publishing it as open source.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a bash script that uses Tesseract 3 or Abbyy OCR 11.
It can batch convert or run in directory monitor mode.

In your case

```
pmocr.sh --batch --target=PDF /path/to/tiff/files
```

See the script here:
https://github.com/deajan/pmOCR